# What was the first Spanish word imported from the Japanese language?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, historia, extranjerismos, diccionarios, japonés

Checking the [NTLLE](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) for some Japanese common words, I see that the word *sake* figured in the Rodríguez Navas dictionary from 1918:

> **Saké**, m. Aguardiente de arroz que se fabrica en Japón.

Another word with more than a century of presence in dictionaries could be *kimono* or *quimono*, as both forms appear in the Alemany y Bolufer dictionary from 1917:

> **QUIMONO**. (Voz japonesa). m. Túnica larga, usada en el Japón por los dos sexos.

So I wonder, what was the first case of a Japanese-imported word that was included in a Spanish dictionary? (Please exclude from the search names of people and places.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Earliest dictionary entries

Excluding proper nouns, the first recorded word in a dictionary with Japanese origins is ***biombo***:

> ***Biombo***, clauſtrum, cancelli, C.
>
> - [*Thesaurus utriusque linguae hispanae et latinae*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=m9vI21IWq4gC&q=biombo), Henríquez (1679)

This even predates the first dictionary recording of the word *Japón* itself (1705, Sobrino), though the name had been used for centuries e.g.:

> La contradicción entre la que nosotros afirmamos que primeramente fueron impresas y publicadas las cartas del **Japón** de los padres jesuítas en castellano, y la declaración de Iñiguez de Lequerica, que dice que se imprimitron en portugués, ...
>
> - [*Informacion de la China, 23 de Nov. 1555*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=17IvAQAAMAAJ&q=%22Jap%C3%B3n%22), Melchior Nuñez Barreto

---

Later than this we have:

| word | first appearance |
| --- | --- |
| ***catana*** | 1706, Stevens *"A New Spanish and English Dictionary"* |
| ***bonze*** | 1721, Bluteau |
| ***catán*** | 1729, Academia Autoridades |
| ***bonzo*** | 1786, Terrero y Pando |
| ***moxa*** | 1787, Terrero y Pando |
| *[**quimón**](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/quim%C3%B3n)* | 1803, Academia Usual |
| ***gingo*** | 1853, Domínguez |
| ***sinto, gingko, ginco*** | 1855, Gaspar y Roig |

and with the onset of the Meiji restoration and continuing into the 20th century we see many more words start entering the lexicon:

| word | first appearance |
| --- | --- |
| *maque, Zumaque de Japón* | 1884, Academia Usual |
| *yen* | 1895, Zerolo |
| *daimío, daimiato, daimonojine, daikoku* | 1895 |
| *micado* | 1899 |
| *fúton*, *samuray*, *harakiri*, *jiu-jiutsu/jujutsu* | 1918 |
| *soja* | 1925 |
| *sogun/xogun* | 1931 |
| *judo/yudo* | 1970 |
| *karate* | 1984 |
| *tatami* | 1985 |
| *bonsái, camicace* | 1992 |

However the majority of these had only short-lived popular use (or indeed never reached widespread adoption) and were dropped from later editions of the dictionaries.

## Earliest documented use

Broadening our search to first documented uses in any Spanish literature, we have this list:

[image: Cronología de los japonesismos]

As you can see from the chronological breakdown, Japanese words entered the Spanish lexicon in 2 broad eras:

> Tras el análisis de la cronología recién expuesta, observamos dos periodos de
> introducción de japonesismos. El primero se sitúa a finales del siglo XVI y comienzos del siglo XVII, esto es, entre 1580 y 1619. Época que coincide con parte de lo que Antonio Cabezas (1994) denominó el siglo ibérico de Japón, un tiempo que se caracteriza por la presencia hispano-portuguesa en el antiguo Nipón y que comprende desde 1543 hasta 1643 (Gil 1991).

> Posteriormente, tras la expulsión de los últimos misioneros y comerciantes y el
> cese de contacto con las naciones hispanas en 1643, Japón vivió casi dos siglos en un aislamiento nacional, sin contacto con España y otras naciones hispanas, hasta la reapertura en la era Meyi, que se extiende desde 1868 hasta 1912 (Gutiérrez-García y Pérez-Gutiérrez en Cid Lucas, 2011: 16, 284). Tras comparar ese periodo de aislamiento con nuestra cronología de japonesismos, se observa que para tal época de inclusión solo se recogen cinco japonesismos (moxa, soja, yinco, sintoísmo y Nipón), los cuales creemos que pasaron al español por intermediación de otras lenguas europeas (holandés, alemán, latín científico, inglés y francés).

> La segunda etapa, que continúa hasta la actualidad, comienza con la apertura
> Meyi, es decir, en 1868; desde entonces el flujo de japonesismos ha sido constante, pero hemos de destacar que a partir de la década de 1960 la entrada de vocablos procedentes de Japón se disparó, siendo la última década del siglo XX la más prolífica, como podemos apreciar en la siguiente línea evolutiva:

> - [*Los japonesismos de la lengua española: historia y transcripción*](https://rio.upo.es/xmlui/handle/10433/3716), Rafael Fernández Mata

---

**Etymologies:**

| Spanish | ← Japanese | (← Middle Chinese) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [*yen*](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5915/26860)<sup>1</sup> | 円 (えん *en*) | 圓 (*ziuᴇn, ɦˠiuᴇn*) |
| *sinto* | 神道 (しんとう *Shintō*) ← (しんたう *Shintau*) | 神道 (*ʑiɪn dɑuX*) |
| *moxa* | 艾 (もぐさ *mogusa*) |  |
| *bonzo* | 凡僧 (ぼんぞう *bonzō*) | 凡 + 僧 (*bjom* + *song*) |
| *maque* | 蒔絵 (まきえ *makie*) |  |
| *biombo* ← `Pt` *biombo* | 屏風 (びょうぶ *byōbu*) |  |
| *catán/catana* | 刀 (かたな *katana*) |  |
| *gingo/gingko*<sup>2</sup> ← `Lat` *ginkgo* | 銀杏 (ぎんなん *ginnan*) | 銀杏／银杏 (*yínxìng*) |
| *quimón/quimono* | 着物 (きもの *kimono*) |  |

<sup>1. At the time the word was loaned to Spanish (and English), え was pronounced /je/, in contrast to modern Japanese pronunciation /e/.</sup>

<sup>2. Change in pronunciation is a result of a [misreading](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ginkgo#Etymology) of the Kanji by Engelbert Kaempfer (the first Westerner to see the species) as *ginkyō* | written *Ginkgo* in his 1712 *Amoenitatum exoticarum politico-physico-medicarum Fasciculi V [...]*), propagated by Carl Linnaeus.</sup>

Comment: Really great answer! I had found "yen" but didn't know that "quimón" was an earlier version of "kimono". And about "catana", a proper katana is longer than it is broad, so the definition as "a broad sword" really puzzles me.

Comment: @Charlie [broadsword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basket-hilted_sword) is a term is used to contrast larger swords with rapiers and smallswords. When referring to European weapons it usually means a double edged basket-hilted sword, but see, for example, the [*Dao*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dao_(sword)) (a single-edged sword similar to the katana), is often referred to as the *Chinese broadsword*.

Comment: Los años 1580 también fueron cuando los primeros japoneses pisaron tierra ibérica: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embajada_Tensh%C5%8D

Comment: El término "Japón" no es de origen japonés, sino que proviene de ["Cipango"](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipango), palabra usada por Marco Polo en su libro *El millón* (o como quiera que se le tenga que llamar en castellano).

Comment: Supongo que como te tomaste el tiempo de investigar no da que cree un post nuevo, pero supongo que deberias tener en cuenta esta informacion para actualizarlo suponiendo que se pueda verificar que es correcta, este archivo lista fechas distintas para algunas de las primeras palabras que encontraste: https://dialnet.unirioja.es/descarga/articulo/5912403.pdf 1580: bonzo, catana. 1590: taicun. 1600: biombo, tatami. .1610: maque