# ¿Se pronuncia "judo" con la "j" española en alguna parte?

Tags: sustantivos, pronunciación, deportes, extranjerismos, japonés

Encuentro en el diccionario lo siguiente:

> **[yudo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=cDZ4AOd)**
>
> Del jap. *judo*, de *jū* 'amable', 'discreto' y *dō* 'camino'.
>
> 1. m. Sistema japonés de lucha, que hoy se practica también como deporte, y que tiene por objeto principal defenderse sin armas mediante llaves y movimientos aplicados con destreza.

Busqué esta palabra porque imaginaba que en español se habría adaptado la pronunciación de la *j* japonesa, y así es. Sin embargo, el diccionario también recoge la grafía original:

> **[judo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=MaQP22f)**
>
> 1. m. **yudo**.

Esta entrada del DLE no está en cursiva, por lo que entiendo que debe pronunciarse con la *j* española. Sin embargo, no recuerdo haber oído a nadie pronunciar "judo" y sí "yudo". Se me ocurren tres opciones:

- La palabra se pronuncia "yudo" y la entrada debería estar en cursiva al ser un extranjerismo crudo, como es el caso de *[jumbo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=McET5B9)*. Toca avisar a la RAE.
- La palabra se pronuncia "yudo" aunque esté escrita con *j* y en letra redonda. ¿Hay otros casos en los que la *j* se pronuncia como *y*? ¿Tal vez *[junior](https://dle.rae.es/?id=McsFhwE)*?
- La palabra se pronuncia "judo". En este caso, ¿en qué región hispanohablante se pronuncia así?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como [judoka](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/users/8910/ukemi?tab=profile) que se ha entrenado en varios clubs, nunca he oído la pronunciación ['xudo].

El DPD afirma que la ortografía es por la influencia de la ortografía inglés/francés, y no una representación de su pronunciación castellana usual. Sin embargo, [recomienda](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=yudo) que "quien escriba *judo* debe pronunciar [júdo] y quien diga [yúdo] debe escribir *yudo*":

> Por influjo de la grafía inglesa y francesa de esta voz, está más extendida en la escritura la forma *judo*, que, sin embargo, suele pronunciarse [yúdo]. Debe evitarse esta discordancia entre grafía y pronunciación: quien escriba *judo* debe pronunciar [júdo] y quien diga [yúdo] debe escribir *yudo*.

El DPD detalla consejos similares sobre la pronunciación de [júnior](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=j%C3%BAnior):

> [Su] uso actual en español se ha revitalizado por influjo del inglés *junior*. Aunque está notablemente extendida la pronunciación inglesa [yúnior], en español debe decirse [júnior], tal como se escribe, con sonido /j/ inicial...

Nota que la palabra muy relacionada (pero menos común) [*jiu-jitsu*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=MUpcyd9) sí aparece en cursiva en su entrada en el DLE.

---

<sup>**1.** No entiendo la prescripción contra el uso de -k- en judoka/yudoka, dado que esta ortografía se usa en [otros préstamos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26259/what-was-the-first-spanish-word-imported-from-the-japanese-language) japoneses: [aikido](https://dle.rae.es/?id=1KWB9PU), [kendo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=MgYfCuk), [kimono](https://dle.rae.es/?id=MhNHQSa), [sake](https://dle.rae.es/?id=X0a9ZmR), [haiku](https://dle.rae.es/?id=JyK0w1N), [sudoku](https://dle.rae.es/?id=YdaBK9p) etc, especialmente considerando que la RAE acepta las dos formas para los practicantes de karate:</sup>

> <sup>El derivado que designa la persona que lo practica puede escribirse *karateca* o *karateka*, con preferencia por la primera de estas formas.</sup>
>   <sup>• [DPD: **karate** o **kárate**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=karate)</sup>

Comment: Similar case of pronunciation not matching spelling: https://www.rae.es/dpd/pijama

Comment: No estoy nada segura de estar entendiendo las transcripciones fonéticas de la RAE. ¿Están usando el IPA? Es que lo de [y] no me cuadra nada.

Comment: @Charo la RAE no usa AFI/IPA sino su propio sistema (como otros diccionarios e.j. [Merriam Webster etc](http://wordyenglish.com/musing/voksa_sinxa_ciste.html)) basado en la ortografía española. Así que [y] = la pronunciación usual de "y" i.e. /ʝ/ y [j] = "j" = /x/.

Comment: ¿No correspondería  [y] de la RAE a [j] IPA? ¿Y [j] RAE no sería [χ] IPA (es la letra griega "chi", pero no sé si se ve bien la diferencia con la "x" -equis-)? ¡Qué lío!

Comment: @Charo Usé "broad transcription" i.e. /x/ ⊃ {[x], [χ], [h]} y /ʝ/ ⊃ {[ɟʝ], [ʝ], [j]} etc. La realización particular depende de la palabra/contexto fonético y el dialecto.

Comment: ¡Ah, OK! Tienes razón, @ukemi. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Por cierto, yo escribo "judo" y pronuncio ['χud̪o].