# ¿Cómo se llama alguien que practica jiu-jitsu brasileño?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, deportes, extranjerismos, portugués, japonés

Se llaman [judoka](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=yudo) y [karateca](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Mg7ESDy) los practicantes de [judo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/se-pronuncia-judo-con-la-j-espa%C3%B1ola-en-alguna-parte) y [karate](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=yudo) respectivamente, y [capoeirista](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capoeira) los qué practican capoeira.

¿Cómo se llaman los practicantes de jiu-jitsu brasileño?

Comment: siguiendo esa lógica sería  *jiu-jitsuka*. Buscando en google devuelve algunos resultados

Comment: @blonfu En inglés suelo oír *jiujiteiro*, del portugués. Para mi (en inglés), *jiujitsuka* significa más alguién que practica jiu-jitsu tradicional/japonés.

Comment: One of my children used to do judo.  His group shared the space with the jiu-jitsu club.  He called th jiu-jitsu people by the technical term *crazy jiu-jitsu people* or *nuts* for short.  I guess in general they were called "the jiu-jitsu club."  Dialogue: A: Who's that who just came in? (*Thinking: He's my size and weight, maybe a sparring partner for me?*)  B: He's Jiu-jitsu.  Forget it.

Comment: Se dice: lutador en  portugues, o sea: luchador. https://super.abril.com.br/historia/como-surgiu-o-jiu-jitsu-brasileiro-e-quais-suas-inovacoes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si nos ceñimos a terminología "oficial":

- La [Real Federación Española de Judo y Deportes Asociados](http://www.rfejudo.com), que para los practicantes de judo utiliza el conocido *[judoka](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=yudo)*,<sup>3</sup> para los de *ju-jutsu* utiliza el más genérico "**deportista**", tanto en sus estatutos y normativa como en sus circulares.

  El mismo término, "**deportista**", es el usado por la [Federación Española de Jiu-Jitsu y Deportes Asociados](http://fejjyda.com/).
- La [Asociación Española de Jiu-Jitsu Brasileño](http://www.aejjb.org/) se refiere a sus afiliados como "**atletas**".
- La [Federación Española de Ju Jitsu Tradicional y Estilos Modernos](http://www.fejjtem.es/) no parece diferenciar más allá de alumno, maestro o afiliado.

Por tanto, si lo que queremos es como digo ceñirnos al lenguaje que usan las federaciones, parece que la opción mayoritaria es: **deportista**.

---

Ahora bien, si buscamos un poco por Google para ver qué palabras usan los propios practicantes, vemos que hay quien usa el derivado "**[jujutsoka](https://www.google.com/search?q=jujutsoka)**" (o "**[jiujitsoka](https://www.google.com/search?q=jiujitsoka)**")<sup>1</sup>. **Lo normal sería que esta palabra vaya cogiendo fuerza poco a poco hasta llegar a ser la denominación más aceptada**, igual que pasó con *judoka*<sup>2</sup> (y quizá, de igual manera, siendo incorporada al DLE como ***yuyutsoca***).

<sub>1. Resultante de aplicar a *ju-jutsu* (o *jiu-jitsu*) el mismo sufijo *-ka* que se aplica a judo para obtener *judoka* y a karate para obtener *karateka* — aunque, curiosamente, trocando la U final de *ju-jutsu* por una O como la de judo.</sub>

<sub>2. Hay que tener en cuenta que el *ju-jutsu* es una disciplina relativamente reciente en España. Mientras que el judo ya podía considerarse popular en la década de los 60 del siglo pasado, no fue hasta los 80 que la RFEJYDA creó una Sección de Jiu-Jitsu, y aún y así hemos tenido que llegar casi al siglo XXI para que el deporte empiece a coger algo de momento. Quiero decir con esto, que aún tendrán que pasar algunas décadas para que se convierta en un deporte lo suficientemente conocido y practicado como para que "el pueblo llano" tenga necesidad de usar una palabra específica para referirse a sus practicantes.</sub>

<sub>3. Aunque incorrecto según la RAE.</sub>

Comment: Interesante lo de *jujuts**o**ka* - parece análogo a la reanálisis del sufijo de *alcohol + ic* → *alcoholic* → *alco + holic* → *choco + holic* → *chocoholic* en inglés (i.e. *judo + ka* → *judoka* → *jud + oka* → *jujuts(u) + oka* → *jujutsoka*)

Answer (score 1):

Es curioso que ni en la Wikipedia en español ni en la Wikipedia en inglés se menciona cómo se llaman los practicantes de este arte marcial. En cambio, en la Wikipedia en japonés sí que he visto algún caso de 柔術家 ("juujutsuka"). Esta palabra combina el nombre del arte marcial, 柔術, ("juujutsu") con 家 ("ka"), usando el mismo kanji que se forma para *karateka* y *judoka*, y que expresaría la idea de "discípulo".

En una [página en francés](http://acjjt.asso.st/lexique.php) he podido contrastar esta información:

| Kanji | Romaji | Hiragana | Francés |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 柔術家 | Juujutsuka | じゅうじゅつか | Jujutsuka, personne pratiquant le Jujutsu |

Si ignoramos el alargamiento de la primera vocal y buscamos "jujutsuka" llegamos a una página del Wikcionario [que dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Jujutsuka):

> Category:Jujutsuka
>
> Practitioners of Jujutsu.
>
> Excludes Brazilian jiu-jitsu practitioners and Judoka see:
>
> Category:Brazilian jiu-jitsu practitioners

¿Cómo? Pues resulta que la palabra "jujutsuka" excluye a los [practicantes del jujutsu brasileño](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Brazilian_jiu-jitsu_practitioners), cuya denominación parece ser sencillamente esa: "practicantes de jujutsu brasileño".

También es posible encontrar, a raíz del [comentario de ukemi](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/30689/c%C3%B3mo-se-llama-alguien-que-practica-jiu-jitsu-brasile%C3%B1o/30692#comment52718_30689) en el que afirma que se usa *jiujiteiro* en inglés, algunas páginas web en español que usan ese mismo término, *jiujiteiro*, pero apenas llegan al centenar.